# "exec myprog &" unexpected behaviour

Tags: bash, shell, unix

When running these shell commands:

```
SH1$ bash
SH2$ exec date &
[1] 375
SH2$ Mon Apr 22 15:04:36 BST 2013
[1]+  Done                    exec date
SH2$
```

the `&` takes precedence over `exec`, and leaves the SH2 process running (same result in ksh and Solaris /bin/sh).

Why is this? Is it well-defined (or required) behaviour, or left up to each implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is standard behavior. See the [POSIX shell grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10), and note that `exec` isn't even explicitly covered; it's treated as an ordinary `cmd_name`.

Answer (score -1):

exec replaces the current shell  with  and executes the command

```
exec date
```

effectively runs date and exits, making you "lose" your original shell

```
exec date &
```

runs exec in a child process.  That is the defined behavior for the & operator.
The result is very much the same as

```
( exec date )
```

&  and ( ) both create a new child process, then execute the command in the context of the new process.

Comment: This is just repeating the OP's findings.

Comment: Right, I see **what** happens, but I'm interested to know why `&` beats `exec`.

Comment: "beats" simply means what executes first. & == take the whole command.  Put it in a child process.  Then execute the command, second.  Just like () beats exec, too.